# How to get the attribute value from EntityReference

Tags: c#, .net

so when my code is:

```
temp.Attributes["new_site"].ToString();
```

the output is Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference, how can I retrieve the value from it?

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the entity of the Reference first.
The Entity Reference contains the Id you can run the query from.

```
OrganizationServiceContext dataContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
Guid siteId = temp.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_site").Id;
Entity site = dataContext.CreateQuery("new_site").FirstOrDefault(ns => ns.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_site") == siteId );
```

Now you have the site Entity that you can all attributes you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
temp.GetAttributeValue<AliasedValue>("new_site").Value
```

or

```
((AliasedValue)temp["new_site"]).Value.ToString()
```

Documentation for [AliasedValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.aliasedvalue.aspx)